# Host header externally

Tags: html, header, navigation, external

I'd like to have everything between my head tag hosted in an external header.html file so that multiple pages can call the same header.html. It'd make editing my header accross multiple pages a lot easier. Any idea how to do this without php?

Thanks.

Comment: But php makes it so much easier. :) Do you not want to use php or do you just not know php? What about javascript?

Answer (score 0):

A (semi-)popular way of doing this is by using [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes), or SSI.

You'd be able to do something like:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->
```

in your pages to include the header.